# How many online courses have been removed due to accessibility laws?

Tags: united-states, reference-request, legal-issues, disability, audio-video-recording

Is there any research/study/survey/database that tried to quantify how many online courses/videos/audio lectures/other educational materials have been removed due to accessibility laws such as the [Americans With Disabilities Act of 1990](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Americans_with_Disabilities_Act_of_1990) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170318150158/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Americans_with_Disabilities_Act_of_1990))?

Comment: Truly interactive online courses are so much newer than the ADA that I doubt many have been removed.  What's at risk is material developed for other purposes that could be made freely available for non-credit study, but that can't be made available "because ADA."  Example: I record my lectures and make "narrated slides" available to my students.  I can do that provided I have no hearing-impaired students in the class.  What I *cannot* do is put my courses on the public web for anyone to use.

Comment: @BobBrown, I don't understand why you cannot put your courses on the public web for anyone to use (supposing for the moment that you have no students in your course needing accommodation...), especially if the material has no larger official status.

Comment: @paulgarrett  Every slide has the school logo.  Removing the logos and regenerating the video file is less work than captioning, but still more work than I am willing to do.